# How to add prop validation for style object in React Native?

Tags: react-native

The PropTypes from 'react-native' package has been deprecated and people are using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types package for prop validation now.

I'm just wondering how do we add validation for styles in the new prop-types package. I think the link above might fail to mention that.

The View.propTypes.style and Text.propTypes.style worked quite well but now deprecated. :(

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native now provides `ViewPropTypes.style` instead of `View.propTypes.style`. You can use it for validating styles like this:

```
import { ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  style: ViewPropTypes.style
};
```